# Robot configuration on Java

Tags: java

I'm having trouble writing a program that will give me a *YES* or *NO* message given the input I enter for my robot. I want to enter my wheel configuration (doesn't matter what it is), and I want the output to show YES if it can move with the wheel configuration I enter.

Thus far, I have this basic code:

```
 If(a=="yes"){
        System.out.println("YES");
    }
    else if(a == "no"){
        System.out.println("NO");
```

Notice how I've not added numbers into the bracket because I'm not sure how to approach this, and it's the first time I'm really testing myself - and I'm new to Java. Help is appreciated as ever.

Comment: use `a.equals("no")` and `a.equals("yes")`

Comment: Thanks. So .equals() tests the string values which is better in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change **==** with **equals**

```
if(a.equals("yes")){
    System.out.println("YES");
}
else if(a.equals("no")){
    System.out.println("NO");
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are comparing Strings you should use `equals()` since that only compares what was written. 
`==` however only returns True if it refers to the same Object.

Do as following:

```
if(a.equals("yes"))
   System.out.println("YES");
else if(a.equals("no"))
   System.out.println("NO");
```